# bpsk demodulation only with STM32

Tags: demodulation, bpsk

for an internship I have to create a communication between 2 devices at 30Khz.
we choose a BPSK modulation.

I create du Tx with a stm32 and a DDS (AD9834).
Now I trying to code the demodulation with a L476 nucleo. and I have some issue.

now I have and acquisition of my signal using ADC (and DAC to see it).

But I don't know how to proceed next. I try to square it, but the result is not good.

If someone can help me ou have a tuto about stm32 and bpsk demodulation only with stm32 it will be very hepfull. thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to be 2 different problems. First, the algorithm. Second, the implementation on an stm32. Have you simulated the algorithm in Matlab/Simulink/Octave/Python? Does it work?

If the algorithm works, then move to the STM32.

Comment: I try an algo in Matlab, but in the same algo I module and demodulate sucessfully. but I can't reproduice it in stm32. I have the signal. in matlab a multiply it by a cos (2 pi F t).what is t in stm32.? I try in excel with the signal value from the adc but I can't demodulate. so your right, 2 issues.

Comment: ok it seem that because my signal has an offset I have some issue.My signal is not between zero but VCC/2 (2.5V) how can I mathematiccaly solved this please?